# Is my proof correct? Let $G$ be a group of order $10989$. Prove that $G$ contains either a normal Sylow $37$-subgroup or a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $10989=3^3\cdot 11\cdot 37$. Prove that $G$ contains either a normal Sylow $37$-subgroup or a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup

It is easy to show that $n_3\in \{1, 37\}$ and $n_{37}\in \{1, 3^3\cdot 11\}$ by Sylow 3rd Theorem.
Suppose that $n_{37}=3^3\cdot 11$.
By Lagrange's Theorem, 
every non-identity element in a Sylow $37$-subgroup is of order $37$.
Hence, 
there are $n_{37}\cdot (37-1)=3^3\cdot 11\cdot 36=10692$ elements of order $37$.
There are $10989-10692=297$ remaining.

If $n_3=37$.
Let $H_1, H_2, ..., H_{37}$ be all the Sylow $3$-subgroups of $G$.
There are **at least** $37\cdot 18+9=675$ elements in $\bigcup_{i=1}^{37}H_i$.
The remaining $297$ elements **can't form** these Sylow $3$-subgroups.
Therefore, $n_3=1$.

There is [another solution](https://www.uvm.edu/~cems/mathstat/grad/math/exams/2009.01_algebra_solutions.pdf). 
But my method is more basic. 
But I have never see this method.
So I worry about that there are some mistake I am not aware.

Comment: Well the fact that each subgroup has $18$ elements distinct to it (not included in any other group) might not be true.

Comment: @Stefan4024 **The minimum** of $|\bigcup_{i=1}^{37} H_i|$ occur in $H_i\cap H_j=K$ for any $i\neq j$, where $|K|=9$.
In that case, 
$|\bigcup_{i=1}^{37} H_i|=n_{37}\cdot |H_i\backslash K|+|K|=37\cdot (37-9)+9=675$.

Comment: But look at this $H_1$ intersects with $H_2$ and have $9$ common elements. Now $H_1$ intersects with $H_3$ and have $9$ common elements (except the identity), other than those included in $H_2$. $H_1$ intersects with $H_4$ and another of the $9$ elements in $H_1$ are the intersection. Now what if intersection of $H_3$ and $H_4$ isn't the identity? Aren't we doublecounting?

Comment: @Stefan4024 Sorry. I can't understand your meaning. Could you please give me more explanation? I have the assumption $H_1\cap H_2=H_2\cap H_3=H_1\cap H_3=K$ and $|K|=9$. So the situation "$H_1$ intersects with $H_3$ and have $9$ common elements (except the identity), other than those included in $H_2$" will not happen.

Comment: You say that the minimum occurs when each pair of subgroups intersect in the same subgroup $K$ of order $9$. How do you justify that claim?

Comment: The group $A_7$ has $70$ Sylow $3$-subgroups of order $9$. According to your reasoning there should be at least $6 \times 70 + 3 = 423$ elements of order $3$ or $9$. But in fact there are only $350$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your example. It is very useful and inspired. I am checking **how** these $70$ Sylow $3$-subgroup intersection.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by Derek Holt. 
Consider the alternating group $A_7$.
Consider the following $6$ Sylow $3$-subgroups.
A triangle stand for a Sylow $3$-subgroup.
(I omitted some product of two $3$-cycles.)

[image]

There are $4\cdot 6+2\cdot 6+1=37$ elements of order $3$.
(No element in $A_7$ is of order $9$.)
But according to my thinking. 
There are at least $6*6+3=39$ elements of order $3$ in these $6$ Sylow $3$-subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of the algebra Ph.D. qualifying exam on Jan. 13, 2009 of the university of Vermont.
The original question is:

Let $G$ be a group of order (note that $10989=3^3\cdot 11\cdot 37$).

1. Compute the number, $n_p$, of Sylow $p$-subgroups permitted by Sylow's Theore for each of $p=3, 11$, and $37$;
   for eachof these $n_p$ give the order of the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subroup.
2. Show that $G$ contains either a normal Sylow $37$-subgroup or a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup.
3. Explain briefly why (in all cases) $G$ has a normal Sylow $11$-subgroup.
4. Deduce that the center of $G$ is nontrivial.

The correct solution of 3. is as following.

We already know that $n_3\in \{1, 37\}$ and $n_{37}\in \{1, 297\}$.
Suppose that $n_3=37$ and $n_{37}=297$.
We prove that there is a contradiction.
Since $n_3=37$,
let $H$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup,
then $[G:N(H)]=n_3=37$ and $N(H)=3^3\cdot 11$.
Since $n_{37}=297$,
there are $36\cdot 297=10692$ elements of order $37$.
There are $10989-10692=3^3\cdot 11$ elements remaining.
Thus, these remaining elements form the unique subgroup $N(H)$ of order $3^3\cdot 11$.
Since $gN(H)g^{-1}$ all are subgroup of order $3^3\cdot 11$ for all $g\in G$,
by the uniqueness of $N(H)$,
$gN(H)g^{-1}=N(H)$ and $N(H)\lhd G$ and $N(N(H))=G$.

Since $H$ is a Sylow $3$-subgroup,
we have $N(N(H))=N(H)$.
Which is a contradiction $N(H)=N(N(H))=G$.

(Or one can show that $H$ is the unique subgroup of order $3^3$ in $N(H)$ by the Sylow's Theorem.
Since $\sigma(H)$ is also a subgroup of order $3^3$ for all automorphism on $N(H)$,
by the uniqueness of $H$,
$\sigma(H)=H$ and $H$ is characteristic in $N(H)$.
Thus, $H\stackrel{\text{char.}}{\leq}N(H)\lhd G$ and $H\lhd G$,
a contradiction.)